# On Key Down Restrict the user to enter Some Special Characters

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I want to restrict the user in toolbar search by not allowing him/her using Some Special Characters like ('/','>','<','|').Please help me out.

```
$("#tblFundComp").bind("keydown",function(e) 
{
  if(e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57 ) 
  { 
    return false; 
  }
  else 
  { 
    return true; 
  }
});
```

I have placed this piece of code after before search function. But this does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want allow only some special characters are entered in the input field of the search toolbar you can use [dataEvents](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) of the `searchoptions` defined using `type:'keypress'` or `type:'keydown'`. It will follows to call `jQuery.bind` and `jQuery.unbind` for the corresponding input field. The code fragment which **allows only digits** is following

```
searchoptions: {
    dataEvents: [
        {
            type: 'keypress', // keydown
            fn: function(e) {
                // console.log('keypress');
                if(e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57) {
                    // allow digits
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // disallow the key
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In the live [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ToolbarSearchValidationKey.htm) you will be **not able to enter digits** in the search field for the 'Name'.

Comment: @ Oleg: Wow thats awesome stuff... As you said i did placed my code in some other place which was causing problem and any ways thanks a lot

Comment: @ Oleg: One more small help i wanna create the context menu which is dynamic in nature which will arise as soon as you rightclick the row. can u please suggest me how this can be done.I have placed my question in the following URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202200/context-menu-in-jqgrid-on-row-click-in-jqgrid