# Context Menu in Jqgrid on Row Click in Jqgrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I am using Jqgrid 3.6 beta version with asp.net and i wanna add dynamic context menu on row selection.When ever user rightclick a row in jqgrid he wants to see some menu like file,edit and other menus. I have completed using single page i.e. both the jqgrid and its parent(JS files) are in single page . But in my main Application I have one master page in which ill define all the JS and seperate page for the content(Jqgrid). So what happens is the same code which is running in single page application is not working in the master detail page.Can any one help me out in this

Comment: My application will be like the following scenario.Let say A.aspx (Similar to Master Page) is there in which i call all tabs and load the tabs and these tabs will be linked with the b.aspx containing jqgrid using the div ill call those clicked page to load inside A.aspx itself. Now in this scenario i put context menu which is working fine in single page application, that is not working to me when i place this in b.aspx in this case What can be done....

Comment: Do you use `jquery.contextmenu.js`? It would be better if you post a code example which can be used to reproduce your problem. Moreover you can any time modify the text of your question. It is better to modify or append the text of the question as to write additional information in the comment.

Comment: The usage of retro verstions (very old versions) of jqGrid is not recommended. Especially the usage of old beta versions. You can download current 3.8.1 version of jqGrid from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i got the solution for the context menu and its working fine. for this to work i needed to add afterinsertrow as well as ondblclickrow function and then it works fine