# jqgrid binding keydown event to cell

Tags: events, jqgrid, cell, keydown

I have a grid like this

```
jQuery("#champDetail").jqGrid({
    data: {},
    height: 300,
    width: 800,
    colNames: ['ID', 'Combination No', 'Qty', 'SMT Program', 'SMT Machine',
               'Product Date', 'Tracking No'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'ID', width: 50 },
        { name: 'CombinationNo', width: 120, sortable: false },
        { name: 'QTY', width: 80, sortable: false, editable: true,
          editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: QTYCheck} },
        { name: 'SMTProg', width: 120, sortable: false, editable: true },
        { name: 'SMTMach', width: 120, sortable: false, editable: true },
        { name: 'ProductDate', width: 120, sortable: false, editable: true },
        { name: 'TrackingNo', width: 100, sortable: false, editable: true }
    ],……………..

    onCellSelect: function(rowid, colid) {
        debugger;
        if (colid == 3) {
            var cm = jQuery("#champDetail").getRowData(rowid)
            var temp = cm["QTY"]
            $("#temp").keydown(function() {
                alert("")
            });
        }
    },……………………………..
```

when select a cell,i want to bind a keydown event to the cell ,

but i can't trigger the event.

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

There are [dataEvents](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) `editoptions` which can be used to the definition of the `colModel`. It allows to make some bindings like `keydown` which you need.

The same option exist also for the `searchoptions`. You can see the corresponding example in my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192768/on-key-down-restrict-the-user-to-enter-some-special-characters/4198475#4198475).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#temp").keydown();
```