# Catching a select change event from within a JqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-events

I am working on an MVC project, which uses JQGrid. In one of my grids, I have a subgrid. Within the subgrid one of the columns is a dropdownlist. I would like to catch the change event of this dropdownlist, so that I can set a default value of the next cell along using the selected item.

I used Firebug to see the Id of the `<select>` html, and tried the following code, which doesn't fire the alert:

```
$('#MySelectId').change(function() {
        alert('Test');
    });
```

This approach worked when using the modal edit form, but I am using inline editing, and would like to catch the event when the user changes the dropdownlist on the grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define `dataEvents` property as the part of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). In the `dataEvents` you defines your custom 'change' event handle and jqGrid will make the binding after the corresponding cell will be initialized in the editing mode. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192768/on-key-down-restrict-the-user-to-enter-some-special-characters/4198475#4198475) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469650/jqgrid-incorrect-select-drop-down-option-values-in-edit-box/4480184#4480184) examples.

Comment: Thanks again Oleg, your a star!

Comment: I am trying to set the value of the textbox next to my dropdown, but I cannot seem to get a handle on it. I have tried using..

Comment: var row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                    var rowId = row.attr('id');
                    $("text#" + rowId + "_MyColumnName", row[0]).html(myValue);

Comment: Sorry, I didn't research this properly, you have already answered this question from another user. I changed my last line to '$("#" + rowId + "_MyColumnName").val(myValue);'

Comment: @Joe: Sorry I don't understand the context of the code. Do you use form editing and you want to change the textedit field of the form for the column "MyColumnName" based on the value `myValue` from the dropdown box? In the case the ids of the edit forms will have ids with the same names like the column name and you can just do `$("#MyColumnName").val(myValue)`. Because I don't exactly understand your code example (especially the context) I am not sure that is what you need.

Comment: @Oleg: I read your answer here[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247138/jqgrid-change-cell-value-and-stay-in-edit-mode) and solved my problem. During my inline edit, I was trying to allow the user to set a in a textbox within the row, using a dropdownbox from the same row. My problem was accessing the textbox to assign it's new value. But After reading your answer I was able to fix the code as in my last comment.

Comment: @Joe: You are write, the answer are very close to your problem. I am glad to hear that I could help you. Best wishes!