# Bind a function to jQGrid filtering's textboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, textbox, keyup

I've written the following code with jquery :

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(
    function (event) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
        if (event.keyCode != 68 && event.keyCode != 186) return;
        var textbox = $(this);
        var clickAttr = textbox.attr('click');
        if (clickAttr != undefined && clickAttr.indexOf('NumericTextBoxKeyPress') > -1) return; 
        var insertedValue = textbox.val();
        insertedValue = insertedValue.replace(/a/g, 'SampleA');
        insertedValue = insertedValue.replace(/b/g, 'SampleB');
        textbox.val(insertedValue);
    }
);
```

It's OK with normal textboxes, but above code doesn't work for jQGrid filtering's textboxes !

[image: Bind a function to jQGrid filtering's textboxes]

Could you please guide me, how I can bind a keyup function to jQGrid filtering's textboxes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [jquery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind event

```
 $('input[type="text"]').live("click", function(){ .... });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the grid and want to bind event at one specified input field of the searching toolbar you can use `dataEvents` of the `searchoptions` the corresponding column of the `colModel` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options)). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4198475/315935) for the code example.

If you need to bind some event like `keyup` to *all* input fields of the searching toolbar of the grid you can do the following:

```
var $grid = $("#list"); // the grid

// create the grid
$grid.jqGrid({
    //... jqGrid options
});

// create the searching toolbar with the line like
$grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {defaultSearch: 'cn'});

// get all input fields of the searching toolbar
var $toolbarRow = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid-view")
                       .find(".ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-toolbar");

// make the binding of all input fields to the event which you need
$toolbarRow.find('input[type="text"]').keyup(function (e) {
    // the code of your event handler
});
```