# Need help in using "editoptions dataEvents" in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Basically, I am new to jqgrid and have been tasked with maintaining a database table that has a relational secondary table.

From what I've read the "editoptions dataEvents" is the ticket.  What I cannot find is an example of how to implement it.  All I've found is code fragments but I am too new to understand how the fragments fit into the overall picture.

A basic and complete example would be wonderful.

Any help would be appreciated.

best regards

Comment: look at [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ToolbarSearchValidationKey.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4198475/315935) which allows to type no digits in the searching field of "Name" column. The `editoption` works exactly in the same way like `searchoptions`.

Comment: Thank you Oleg,  That is a big help.  I'm sure that I will have more questions and places to get stuck but this moves the needle a bit.  The trouble is that I am jumping in at the deep end and am still don't know how to swim.  :-)

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.

Comment: I have a follow up question on your example Oleg.
How does the select box only appear on the first line?
Also, I need to be able to add a select box to each line in the grid so I can select multiple options for each row.  

I have primary and secondary tables that relate to each other and if secondary rows exist for the primary I want to put them in a drop down box on each row in the grid.

Comment: "The first line" is the searching toolbar added by `filterToolbar` method. The body of the grid (other rows) just display all the data loaded in the grid. The searching toolbar (the filter toolbar) allows to reduce the display results to the subset of rows with the corresponding values in the column.

Comment: Is there a way to add a select box to each row?  In my example I would like to list the states we have stores in then in each row have a select box that will contain an entry for each store within that state.  I have this relationship working with a subgrid but I am thinking a select box will look better.

Comment: Ok, that helps with the filterToolbar method but what about a drop down/select box in the data grid?  Is that possible, recommended?  What other techniques are used for complex data entry and relationships?

Comment: Sorry, but it's long discussion. You ask **too common** questions. In general one need first **display** some information in grid. The user can see **only one text option from the <select>**. So the standard way which one uses in jqGrid is just displaying the texts in grid. One can start inline editing on click on row/cell, double click, click on "Edit" button in the row or on button in navigation bar *to start editing*. In editing mode the user sees `<select>` and the user can changes the value. After modification the line the user can save the changes and the row will become back to texts.