# JqGrid with autocompletion textfiel instead of dropdown list +Update

Tags: jqgrid

Right now i have a jqgrid with 3 columns as dropdown lists and some other columns as normal text.

I was inspired by this [jqGrid toolbar search with autocomplete using json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037104/jqgrid-toolbar-search-with-autocomplete-using-json-data) and wanted to try to do instead of my dropdown lists an autocompletion textbox which retrive data same way as my dropodwns.
 I am trying to do this atm on a column with a textbox. The problem is when i am running the code and entering  column with my autocompletion field i just gettion "loading..." it looks like i am not retriving data the right way..

code:

http://pastebin.com/95FUe8ys

**UPDATE**

Aditional info:

Column which i try to make autocompleetable is named EanNummer

{ name: 'EanNummer', index: 'EanNummer', width: 65, sortable: true, editable: true },

my action have to happend on load which looks like this:

loadComplete: function () {

```
              if (grid.getGridParam('datatype') === 'json') {
                  // build the set 'source' parameter of the autocomplete
                  grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'EanNummer', {
                      searchoptions: {
                          sopt: ['bw'],
                          dataInit: function (elem) {
                              $(elem).autocomplete({
                                  source: '@Url.Action("GetCustumer3")',
                                  delay: 0,
                                  minLength: 0
                              });
                          }
                      }
                  });

              }

              jQuery("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: "cn" }); // Call to fix client-side sorting

          },
```

where '@Url.Action("GetCustumer3")' at source is a method in controller which looks like this:

```
    public JsonResult GetCustumer3()
    {
        string vendorId = "";
        var username = "";
        var name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        var charArray = name.Split("\\".ToCharArray());
        username = charArray.Last();
        vendorId = service.GetVendorIdByUsername(username);

        var list = new List<string>();
        var customcat1 = service.GetAllIntCustomCategory1(vendorId);
        foreach (var custom1 in customcat1)
        {
            if (custom1.SortOrderId == 0)
                custom1.CustomName = "";
            list.Add(custom1.CustomName);
        }

        return Json(list);
    }
```

i am returning a list of strings as a jsonresult to source, but can jqgrid find out to do it that way??