# Jqgrid search toolbar filter unique drop lists

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've used the example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328072/can-jqgrid-support-dropdowns-in-the-toolbar-filter-fields) and it works great to create a unique drop list in the search tool bar based on the column data. However, if I have more than one page of data then the drop list is only populated from the first page. I'm new to jquery and jqgrid and have not been able to find a solution to this. Any idea's?

Thanks.

Here is the code copied from the post linked above.

```
var mydata = [
    {id:"1", Name:"Miroslav Klose",     Category:"sport",   Subcategory:"football"},
    {id:"2", Name:"Michael Schumacher", Category:"sport",   Subcategory:"formula 1"},
    {id:"3", Name:"Albert Einstein",    Category:"science", Subcategory:"physics"},
    {id:"4", Name:"Blaise Pascal",      Category:"science", Subcategory:"mathematics"}
],
grid = $("#list"),
getUniqueNames = function(columnName) {
    var texts = grid.jqGrid('getCol',columnName), uniqueTexts = [],
        textsLength = texts.length, text, textsMap = {}, i;
    for (i=0;i<textsLength;i++) {
        text = texts[i];
        if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
            // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
            textsMap[text] = true;
            uniqueTexts.push(text);
        }
    }
    return uniqueTexts;
},
buildSearchSelect = function(uniqueNames) {
    var values=":All";
    $.each (uniqueNames, function() {
        values += ";" + this + ":" + this;
    });
    return values;
},
setSearchSelect = function(columnName) {
    grid.jqGrid('setColProp', columnName,
                {
                    stype: 'select',
                    searchoptions: {
                        value:buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames(columnName)),
                        sopt:['eq']
                    }
                }
    );
};
grid.jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: 'local',
    colModel: [
        { name:'Name', index:'Name', width:200 },
        { name:'Category', index:'Category', width:200 },
        { name:'Subcategory', index:'Subcategory', width:200 }
    ],
    sortname: 'Name',
    viewrecords: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    ignoreCase: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    height: "auto",
    caption: "How to use filterToolbar better locally"
}).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
          {edit:false, add:false, del:false, search:false, refresh:false});

setSearchSelect('Category');
setSearchSelect('Subcategory');

grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'Name',
            {
                searchoptions: {
                    sopt:['cn'],
                    dataInit: function(elem) {
                        $(elem).autocomplete({
                            source:getUniqueNames('Name'),
                            delay:0,
                            minLength:0
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar',
            {stringResult:true, searchOnEnter:true, defaultSearch:"cn"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `datatype: 'local'` you have the information which you need already in `mydata`. Alternative you can use `var gridData = grid[0].p.data` or which is the same `var gridData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','data')` to get the grid contain of **all grid pages**. So instead of `textsLength` and `texts[i]` in the `getUniqueNames` function you could use `gridData.length` and `gridData[columnName]` or `String(gridData[columnName])`.

Comment: Thanks Oleg this sounds like a step in the right direction. However, I'm not sure how to apply these changes to the code above to make it work. Again I'm really really new to Jqgrid and Javascript for that matter and have much to learn. So if you don't mind can you show where to change the code? Thanks again.

Comment: @kes9: It's not so difficult. I'll make it for you later (I am just back from the customers and have at home something to do :-)).

Comment: Hey Oleg, I figured it out based on your suggestions. In the script above I substituted grid.jqGrid('getCol',columnName) with grid[0].p.data and substituted text[i] with text[i][columnName] and it works perfectly. I appreciate all the help. Thanks again.

Comment: @kes9: Exactly! It's what I mean. It's much better that you did it yourself. In the case you can better keep. You are welcome!

Comment: I've been using this dynamic drop down for a while now and it works great but now I want to change from a local data array to json data type. Now the filters come up empty. Can this be done with json data? Any advice?

Comment: @kes9: You can build `searchoptions.value` *on the server side* and returns the values back as the part of the server. You can see the full server response (inclusive any additional data) in `loadComplete (data)` or in `beforeProcessing (data)` callback. Alternatively you can use `dataUrl` and optionally `buildSelect` property instead of `value` property of `searchoptions`. In the way you can also build the list of possible values *on the server side*.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to send the list to the page outside of jqgrid.  jqgrid will only pull a page at a time and does not know about all your other data if you are using it in ajax mode.

If this is just a matter of using the mydata that you have above and the data is all in the scope of js, but just on another page (result set on jqgrid) why dont you build the list and use that in place of the var called texts.  You are only going over the page data, not all the data you load in.  Does this make sense?