# Jqgrid search toolbar filter unique drop lists with Json

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I have created a filter toolbar based on this  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328072/can-jqgrid-support-dropdowns-in-the-toolbar-filter-fields).  I have an odd problem; this only works when I have firebug breakpoints set, otherwise, the dropdown only displays 'All'. The grid is set with datatype:'json', loadonce:true. One more point; this grid also has a sub grid. Any idea on how to get this working?

```
 grid = $("#dealsgrid"),
 getUniqueNames = function(columnName) {
       var texts = grid.jqGrid('getCol', columnName); 
       var uniqueTexts = [];
       var textsLength = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
       var text, textsMap = {}, i;
       for (i = 0; i < textsLength; i++) {
          text = texts[i];
          if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
            // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
            textsMap[text] = true;
            uniqueTexts.push(text);
          }
       }
       return uniqueTexts;
     }, 
 buildSearchSelect = function(uniqueNames) {
       var values = ":All";
       $.each(uniqueNames, function() {
          values += ";" + this + ":" + this;
       });
      return values;
   }, 
 setSearchSelect = function(columnName) {
      grid.jqGrid(
        'setColProp',
        columnName,
        {
            stype : 'select',
            searchoptions : {
                value : buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames(columnName)),
                sopt : [ 'eq' ]
            }
        });
 };
```

I after declaring the grid, my column model looks like this:

```
    colModel:[ 
               {name:'CM',index:'CM', width:50,editable:false},
               {name:'DealNo',index:'DealNo',width:75,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true, size:10},search:true, stype:'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq']}},
               {name:'KeyDate',index:'KeyDate',width:100, search:false, align:"right",formatter:'date'},
               {name:'VendorNo',index:'VendorNo', width:75,search:true},
               {name:'VendorName',index:'VendorName', width:100,search:true},
               {name:'ItemQty',index:'ItemQty', width:75,search:false},{name:'StartDate',index:'StartDate',width:100,align:"right",formatter:'date',search:false},
               {name:'EndDate',index:'EndDate',width:100, align:"right",formatter:'date',search:false},
               {name:'ActiveStartDate',index:'ActiveStartDate',width:100, align:"right",formatter:'date',search:false, sorttype:"date", editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},                   {name:'ActiveEndDate',index:'ActiveEndDate',width:100,align:"right",formatter:'date',search:false, sorttype:"date",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},             
               {name:'DealType',index:'DealType', width:75,search:false}

           ],
```

and finally, my call to create the filterToolBar and populate the dropdown

```
        setSearchSelect('CM'); 
        grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'Name', {
        searchoptions : {
            sopt : [ 'cn' ],
            dataInit : function(elem) {
               $(elem).autocomplete({
                  source : getUniqueNames('Name'),
                  delay : 0,
                  minLength : 0
               });
           }
        }

    });
    grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
       stringResult : true,
       searchOnEnter : true,
       defaultSearch : "eq"
    });
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Could you please reproduce your problem with jsfiddle so we can take a look. I already created one for your with the proper resources (css and js) included - http://jsfiddle.net/yTX3P/1/ Don't forget to save it.

Comment: @Martijn B My code is available at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/yTX3P/4/embedded/result/)

Comment: Your example doesn't reproduce the problem. There is no data available. I can't help you this way. What you can try is putting a breakpoint on return uniqueTexts from the getUniqueNames method and check which values are being returned. If this is empty you have to focus on the getUniqueNames method.

Comment: @Martijn B
When I put a break on return uniqueTexts, I get nothing, however, when I put the break on setSearchSelect('CM'); I get the list of unique names.  I don't need to step through the code, I just need to hit run.  Is it possible that I need to put a wait statement somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed my old answer now we know that your function is returning something (if you put a breakpoint on it). Could it be that your grid has not yet loaded the data before getUniqueNames is called? This explains that if you put a breakpoint on it, it has more time to load the data before the getUniqueNames is called.

So if you call the setSearchSelect in the gridComplete or maybe even the loadComplete it should be ok. Maybe you even have to set the async property of the grid to false. I would need to check that with my own code, so I could provide you with a example. I will do this first thing in the morning. In the mean time you could try it yourself by doing some adjustments based on the info above.

```
   $('#yourgrid').jqGrid({
    ...,
    async: false,
    loadComplete/gridComplete: function() { setSearchSelect('CM'); }
   });
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that in the example that I put up as well and edited it so that  
    var textsLength = texts.length  
var results returns [] if there is no break, otherwise it returns  
     ["MR", "CW", "TB"]

Comment: Thanks for your help - I finally got it working!  As it turns out, I had to put everything in the loadComplete function  
        async: false,
            loadComplete:function(){
            setSearchSelect('CM');
            $("#dealsgrid").setColProp('Name', {searchoptions : {sopt : [ 'cn' ],dataInit : function(elem) {$(elem).autocomplete({source : getUniqueNames('Name'),delay : 0,minLength : 0});}}});
            $("#dealsgrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult : true,searchOnEnter : true,defaultSearch : "cn"});
            },