# How to add DropdownMenu for JqgridFilterToolbar Column

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, jqgrid

Hii Guys!!!
              I made jqgrid in which i added a FilterToolbar.Now as per my need i need dropdownmenu for unique values in  FilterToolbar column.I am using asp.net...

Here is my code...

```
 $(function () {
        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            height: 250,
            colNames: ['UserID', 'UserName', 'FirstName', 'MiddleName', 'LastName', 'EmailID'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'UserID', index: 'UserID', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'UserName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'FirstName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'MiddleName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'LastName', width: 100, sortable: true },
                    { name: 'EmailID', width: 150, sortable: true }
                ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#UsersGridPager',
            sortname: 'UserID',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',
            autowidth:true

            //caption: 'JSON Example'
        });

        $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#UsersGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });

       $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter:true, defaultSearch: 'cn' });
       $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#UsersGrid-pager', { caption: "Filter", title: "Toggle Searching Toolbar", buttonicon: 'ui-icon-pin-s', onClickButton: function () { $("#UsersGrid")[0].toggleToolbar(); }
});
```

Plz guys help me to get the solution..
Thanx in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is the usage [stype: "select"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options). If you want fill dropdown with unique value from the column you can do this either on the server side or on the client side. If you provide all possible the unique values on the server side in form HTML fragment of `<select>` you can specify `dataUrl` option of `searchoptions` (or `editoptions`). If you provide the data on the client side you can specify `value` property of `searchoptions` (or `editoptions`) instead. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329014/315935) you will find the example of possible implementation.