# Drop down not working in Filter toolbar for jqgrid 4.6.0 version?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I want support for drop-downs in the toolbar filter fields as Filter toolbar drop-down not working in jqgrid 4.6.0 version. But it is working in 3.8 .version

I have referred the [link](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ToolbarSearchValidation.htm) for 3.8.

Please help me to fix in 4.6.0 version.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var categories = ["All", "sport", "science"];
            var categoriesStr = ":All;1:sport;2:science";
            var subcategories = ["All", "football", "formel 1", "physics", "mathematics"];
            var subcategoriesStr =":All;1:football;2:formel 1;3:physics;4:mathematics";
            var mydata = [
                {id:0, Name:"Lukas Podolski",     Category:1, Subcategory:1},
                {id:1, Name:"Michael Schumacher", Category:1, Subcategory:2},
                {id:2, Name:"Albert Einstein",    Category:2, Subcategory:3},
                {id:3, Name:"Blaise Pascal",      Category:2, Subcategory:4}
            ];

            var grid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                data: mydata,
                datatype: 'local',
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200},
                    { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 200, formatter:'select', stype: 'select',
                      sorttype: function(cell) {return categories[cell];},
                      edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: categoriesStr },
                      searchoptions:{ sopt:['eq'] }
                    },
                    { name: 'Subcategory', index: 'Subcategory', width: 200, formatter:'select', stype: 'select',
                      sorttype: function(cell) {return categories[cell];},
                      edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: subcategoriesStr},
                      searchoptions:{ sopt:['eq'] }
                    }
                ],
                sortname: 'Name',
                viewrecords: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                ignoreCase: true,
                pager: '#pager',
                caption: "Setting filter in the filter toolbar"
            }).jqGrid('navGrid','#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh:false });
            grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch : "cn", beforeSearch: function() {
                //alert("verifying the data");
                var postData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','postData');
                // we use `stringResult: true` so decoding of the search parameters are a little complex
                var searchData = jQuery.parseJSON(postData.filters);
                for (var iRule=0; iRule<searchData.rules.length; iRule++) {
                    if (searchData.rules[iRule].field === "Name") {
                        var valueToSearch = searchData.rules[iRule].data;
                        if (valueToSearch.length != 5) {
                            alert ("The search string MUST de 5 charachters length!");
                            return true;    // error
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }});
        });
```

I have attached 4.6.0 version screen shot.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My demo, which you reference in your question, is really old. I created it for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329014/315935).

I updated the demo the [the following](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FillToolbarSearchFilter4.htm) which uses jqGrid 4.6.0. It uses the following code

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var mydata = [
            {id: "10", Name: "Miroslav Klose",     Category: "Sport",   Subcategory: "Football"},
            {id: "20", Name: "Michael Schumacher", Category: "Sport",   Subcategory: "Formula 1"},
            {id: "30", Name: "Albert Einstein",    Category: "Science", Subcategory: "Physics"},
            {id: "40", Name: "Blaise Pascal",      Category: "Science", Subcategory: "Mathematics"}
        ],
        $grid = $("#list"),
        getUniqueNames = function (columnName) {
            var texts = this.jqGrid("getCol", columnName), uniqueTexts = [],
                textsLength = texts.length, text, textsMap = {}, i;
            for (i = 0; i < textsLength; i++) {
                text = texts[i];
                if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
                    // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
                    textsMap[text] = true;
                    uniqueTexts.push(text);
                }
            }
            return uniqueTexts;
        },
        buildSearchSelect = function (uniqueNames) {
            var values = ":All";
            $.each(uniqueNames, function () {
                values += ";" + this + ":" + this;
            });
            return values;
        },
        setSearchSelect = function (columnName) {
            this.jqGrid("setColProp", columnName, {
                stype: "select",
                searchoptions: {
                    value: buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames.call(this, columnName)),
                    sopt: ["eq"]
                }
            });
        };

    $grid.jqGrid({
        data: mydata,
        datatype: "local",
        colModel: [
            {name: "Name"},
            {name: "Category"},
            {name: "Subcategory"}
        ],
        cmTemplate: {width: 200},
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        sortname: "Name",
        viewrecords: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        ignoreCase: true,
        pager: "#pager",
        height: "auto",
        caption: "How to use filterToolbar better locally"
    }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager",
        {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false});

    setSearchSelect.call($grid, "Category");
    setSearchSelect.call($grid, "Subcategory");

    $grid.jqGrid("setColProp", "Name", {
        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ["cn"],
            dataInit: function (elem) {
                $(elem).autocomplete({
                    source: getUniqueNames.call($(this), "Name"),
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        var $myGrid, grid;
                        $(elem).val(ui.item.value);
                        if (typeof elem.id === "string" && elem.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                            $myGrid = $(elem).closest("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").next("div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv").find("table.ui-jqgrid-btable").first();
                            if ($myGrid.length > 0) {
                                grid = $myGrid[0];
                                if ($.isFunction(grid.triggerToolbar)) {
                                    grid.triggerToolbar();
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            // to refresh the filter
                            $(elem).trigger("change");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar",
        {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: "cn"});
});
```

Comment: @Oleg Hi Oleg - do we need to put this in the `gridComplete` function if we are not using `local` data? I have a grid pulling data from a JSON source and all I'm getting are `select` boxes with one option in them: `All`

Comment: @FastTrack: If you change the content of the grid *dynamically* you should update selects and *recreate* the searching toolbar. The callback `gridComplete` could be the wrong place and the version of jqGrid which you use could be very important. For example jqGrid 4.6 trigger `jqGridAfterGridComplete` event inside of `setRowData`, but `gridComplete` will be not called. It's better if you describe your problem **detailed** in new question.

Comment: @Oleg here is my question, please help if you can! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153355/dynamic-dropdown-in-jqgrid-based-on-dynamic-data

Comment: @Oleg I have another question for you in regards to this answer. Could you please check it out when you get a chance? Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262903/jqgrid-update-filter-toolbar-dropdowns-after-search

Comment: @Oleg I see you seem to know a lot about the jqGrid, Can you please look into this question and please guide me on this `jqGrid Multi select` issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528454/jqgrid-add-multi-select-column-filter-to-a-specific-column

Comment: @BAVB: Your question contains no test data and no demo. It's unclear, which version of jqGrid, which CSS framework and in which version you use (can use). It would be very important to know, where you need to use multiselect: in filter toolbar or in searching dialog or in both. So it's difficult to answer on your question directly. What I can do is to post some demo, which demonstrates the usage of `searchoptions: { generateValue: true, sopt: ["in"], attr: { multiple: "multiple", size: 7 }, dataInit: dataInitMultiselect }` in recent version of free jqGrid.