# jqGrid Update Filter Toolbar Dropdowns after Search

Tags: jqgrid

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140997/drop-down-not-working-in-filter-toolbar-for-jqgrid-4-6-0-version/29141713#29141713) from @Oleg, I would like to know how we can update the filter toolbar after a search has been performed.

For example:

In [Oleg's example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FillToolbarSearchFilter4.htm), if you select the `Sport` option from the `Category` dropdown, the `Subcategory` dropdown still has `Football, Formula 1, Mathematics and Physics` as options even though they are not shown in the grid after the search.

How can we update that code so that, for example, when I select `Sport` from the `Category` dropdown, the filter toolbar is updated so that the dropdowns only have options from the new set of data after the search?

I've been trying to "refresh" or "update" the filter toolbar after a search has been performed, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

What you mean is dependent selects. I posted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480184/315935) with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditWithDependendSelects2_.htm) which demonstrates the solution. I plan to implement soon new feature in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (it's my fork of jqGrid) the possibility to refresh the options of select. It will make the implementation of dependent select much more simple. Currently one have to refill all options manually.