# External filter dropdown for jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid with say 3 columns 1) ID, 2) Country, 3 Description

```html
id| country | Description  
1 | France  | this is just a test    
2 | China   | this is just a test  
3 | Russia  | this is just a test  
4 | France  | this is just a test   
5 | France  | this is just a test
```

Now what is needed is a external select dropdown which contains unique country names

Like for the above the dropdown values will be
France
China
Russia

1) Is it possible to achieve this via Jquery or something without a DB Hit to populate the dropdown?
2) This would be simple, but upon selection the grid needs to filter for the country selected

The select Dropdown is external in the page and not inside the jqgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which `datatype` you use? Which version and fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid version <=4.7)?

In general you can follow the idea described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141713/315935) (modification of [the old one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329014/315935)) to generate unique values in the column and to use there in select or `autocomplete`. The old answer uses internal select and input of [the filter toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching), but you can use external elements in the same way.

[One more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UsageFormetterSelect2_inlineEditing.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33475971/315935) uses [select2](https://select2.github.io/) control, which I personally like. It has the advantages of select and autocomplete.