# dropdown not being populated in filter toolbar in jquery grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140997/drop-down-not-working-in-filter-toolbar-for-jqgrid-4-6-0-version/29141713#29141713) and also this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328072/can-jqgrid-support-dropdowns-in-the-toolbar-filter-fields) Both are Oleg's solutions to the problem. I used the same solution but the drop down doesn't populate with the values except for 'All'
I placed the code in load complete and I see the values when you call the 'setSearchSelect' function but only 'All' shows up in the dropdown. 
Here's the code-

```
setupGrid: function (grid, pager) {
            $(grid).jqGrid({
                datatype: 'local', // set datatype to local to not inital load data
                mtype: 'GET',
                url: swUrl + ptSearchDashboardUrl,
                colNames: colNames,
                colModel: colModel,
                altRows: false,
                pager: $(pager),
                loadonce: true,
                sortable: true,
                multiselect: true,
                viewrecords: true,
                loadComplete: function (data) {
                        //setSearchSelect.call($grid, 'RequestType');
                    //setSearchSelect.call($grid, 'Country');
                },
                onSelectRow: function() {
                    var checkedIDs = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
                    if (checkedIDs.length > 0)
                        $("#ReassignBtn").show();
                    else
                        $("#ReassignBtn").hide();
                }
            }).navGrid(pager, { add: false, edit: false, del: false }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ current: true }]);

            setSearchSelect.call($grid, 'RequestType');
            setSearchSelect.call($grid, 'Country');
            $grid.jqGrid("setColProp", "Name", {
                searchoptions: {
                    sopt: ["cn"],
                    dataInit: function(elem) {
                        $(elem).autocomplete({
                            source: getUniqueNames.call($(this), "Name"),
                            delay: 0,
                            minLength: 0,
                            select: function(event, ui) {
                                var $myGrid, grid;
                                $(elem).val(ui.item.value);
                                if (typeof elem.id === "string" && elem.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                                    $myGrid = $(elem).closest("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").next("div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv").find("table.ui-jqgrid-btable").first();
                                    if ($myGrid.length > 0) {
                                        grid = $myGrid[0];
                                        if ($.isFunction(grid.triggerToolbar)) {
                                            grid.triggerToolbar();
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    // to refresh the filter
                                    $(elem).trigger("change");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            $(grid).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult:true, searchOnEnter:true, defaultSearch:"cn"});
        }
```

This is from the UI - I can only see one option value even though there are many.

```
<td class="ui-search-input">
    <select name="RequestType" id="gs_RequestType" style="width: 100%;">
        <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you use `getUniqueNames` which uses `.jqGrid("getCol", columnName)` to get the data from the column. On the other side you use `datatype: 'local'` to create **empty grid**. The calls `setSearchSelect.call($grid, 'RequestType');`, `setSearchSelect.call($grid, 'Country');` and `getUniqueNames.call($(this), "Name")` will be made **before** the grid will be filled with data. Thus you fill set empty set of select elements.

I suppose that you change later the `datatype` to `"json"` or `"xml"` and reload the grid. Only after your get response from the server you will ba able to fill the select values. I would suggest you to use `beforeProcessing`, which will be called after loading the data from the server, but before processing of the data. You can modify `getUniqueNames` and `setSearchSelect` so that it get the data from the input data directly and calls `setColProp`. Finally you should call `destroyFilterToolbar` and call `filterToolbar` once more to create the filter toolbar with the current data.

Comment: Yes, you are right. on loadComplete the calls are made before and after the grid gets loaded. after reloading, dropdowns still show just 'All' option. Data type is always local. i will use beforeProcessing and will let you know. Thanks for ur quick response.

Comment: @HappyLee: You ca't use `beforeProcessing` if the `datatype` is **always** `"local"`. It will be never called. I supposed that you change the `datatype` *later* to `"json"` (or `"xml"`) and `.trigger("reloadGrid")` because you `url` option of jqGrid. It `datatype` is really **always** `"local"` then you should include the code fragment which shows how you fill the grid with the data.

Comment: initially the datatype is 'json' . Anyway,calling the methods 'setSearchSelect', 'getUniqueNames' in beforeProcessing event, fixed the problem. It works perfectly now. You are a person with tremendous knowledge. thanks for all you do here :)

Comment: I also used this link for reference which is again @Oleg's answer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407378/jqgrid-using-beforeprocessing-to-populate-filtertoolbar-selection-boxes