# jqGrid - multi select column filter - is there any way to send mult-values in array format like "?key=['a','b']" not "?key=a,b"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, request, jqgrid

I am following the kind explanation and guidance from @Oleg which are super helpful on this page:
[jqGrid add multi select column filter to a specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528454/jqgrid-add-multi-select-column-filter-to-a-specific-column)

Everything is okay and working fine but the problem is it sends multi-selected values in comma separated as query string

so currently, it sends in this format

```
..... ?keyA=a&keyB=familyName1, givenName1, famylyName2, givenName2
```

If they are not name, I can split by comma in the backend.
But those names come with commas inside.

So, what I want to do is send those query parameters in a different form such as

```
...... ?keyA=a&keyB=fname1, gname1&keyB=fname2, gname2
```

OR

```
...... ?keyA=a&keyB=["familyName1, givenName1", "famylyName2, givenName2"]
```

OR even the below would work

```
...... ?keyA=a&keyB="familyName1, givenName1", "famylyName2, givenName2"
```

I don't know where to modify to control the format.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: I ask this since in Guriddo jqGrid there is a option to configure the split separator witha value what you want.

Comment: @TonyTomov Thank you for your comment. The current system is using 4.x version free jqGrid. If it is free jqGrid, that option is not available?
Anyways, I will check it one more time if there is that option. Actually, I went through the document many times but I might have missed it. Thanks.

Comment: You can [look here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#toolbar-search-options) - see option splitSelect

Comment: @TonyTomov Oh! I didn't know the existence of that document. I only used the Wiki page. I will use the split option ad work today. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Be carefully with the versions used (free - jqGrid or Guriddo jqGrid)- I'm not sure from which version is available this option.

Comment: @TonyTomov Sadly it doesn't work. I guess because we are using too old version. Due to other dependencies I cannot upgrade the version of jqGrid to 5.x.
Thank you though...... I will use encoding/decoding the delimiter ',' as workaround.