# JQGrid and Result search

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I've implemented a JQGrid table with `loadonce:true` like this :

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
     datatype: 'jsonstring',
     datastr : maVarJSON,
     colNames:['AA','BB', 'CC','DD','EE','FF'], 
     colModel :[ 
            {name:'invid', index:'invid', align:'center'}, 
            {name:'invdate', index:'invdate'},
            {name:'amount', index:'amount', align:'right'}, 
            {name:'tax', index:'tax', align:'right'}, 
            {name:'total', index:'total', align:'right'}, 
            {name:'note', index:'note'} 
     ],
     pager: jQuery('#pager'),
     rowNum: 50,              
     rowList: [50, 100], 
     caption: '',            
     height: 470,
     width: 1000,       
     loadonce: true          
});
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{afterSearch: function(){
            var rowsFiltered = jQuery("#list").getRowData();
 }});
```

My problem is :
I have 500 rows in `maVarJSON`. I see 50 rows and 10 pages.
 I decide to filter my column AA. Only 100 rows accept this filter. So, I see 50 rows and 2 pages.
I would get the 100 rows data. (The method `jQuery("#list").getRowData()` give me only the 50 first rows data.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `getRowData` get the data from the *current* page only. If you need get all the grid data you can use `getGridParam` to get `'data'` parameters and get *all* grid data. I don't really understand what you want to do with the data inside of `afterSearch` callback. The goal of `filterToolbar` to display the data for the user and not to get you JavaScript interface to filter some JavaScript data.

By the way you can remove `caption: ''` option which is default, remove `loadonce: true` which will be ignored for local data inclusive `datatype: 'jsonstring'` and replace `pager: jQuery('#pager')` option to `pager: '#pager'`. If you would use `pager: jQuery('#pager')` jqGrid will have to convert it to `pager: '#pager'` itself internally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In fact, the objects (represented by rows ; 1 object=1 row) are also displayed in a google map div in my application. So, I wanted to show/hide these objects that accept/not accept the filter.

Comment: @user1268560: Sorry, but I still not understand what you want. To "accept/not accept the filter" you should use probably [beforeSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) and not `afterSearch`. You can analyse the *filter* and not the data. See an example in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4184035/315935). If you have some problems with `rowNum: 50` you can increase the value. In any way I would recommend you to add `gridview: true` for better performance of the grid.

Comment: I've added gridview to true. The example helped me to do what i wanted to. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You will push only the searched for rows across all pages to the obj.items object:

```
var obj         = new Object();
var numpages = jQuery(id).getGridParam('lastpage');
obj.items       = new Array();  
var realname = id.split("_");
realname = "input_jqGridPager_" + realname[1];
var curpage = jQuery('#'+realname);
curpage = curpage.children('input');
curpage = curpage[0].value;

for (var i = 1; i <= numpages; i++)
{
    jQuery(id).trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:i}]);

    selRowIds   = jQuery(id).jqGrid ('getRowData'); 
    obj.count       = selRowIds.length;
    for(elem in selRowIds) {
        obj.items.push(selRowIds[elem]);
    }

}
jQuery(id).trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:curpage}]);
```